# How to create a shadow in a boxview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to create a Box view like material design card with shadow drop

I have written a custom render to add the shadow effect in android. but in iOS, it's not working

Comment: Use [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame?view=xamarin-forms) instead a BoxView, Frame layout has the `HasShadow` property, it works fine on both Android (api 21 and above) and iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have put your BoxView inside a frame and enabled the HasShadow property of it

```
<Frame ConnerRadius="5" HasShadow="true">
<BoxView/>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<Frame ConnerRadius="5" HasShadow="true"></Frame>
```